# A mathematical analysis of a single fixed pulley

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, free-body-diagram, string

I think Physics stack exchange is correct for this.
Suppose we take a simple fixed pulley like this:

[image]

Suppose the string is inextensible, massless and strong. One end of the string is connected to load  $L$ and the effort $E$ is applied at other end of the string. The load $L$ and effort $E$ both act downwards. Here, the tension throughout the string is uniform. I was trying to prove this. Please let me know if the proof is correct.
Let the radius be $r$. If the entire system is balanced,i.e,if the pulley is not rotating,then ideally the net anticlockwise and clockwise moments must cancel each other.To speak mathematically, $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} Lr-Er=0$ where $Lr-Er$ is the net moment about a given point $p$ where forces are acted upon by the string through the load and effort. If $L-E\neq0$ then we find that the given sum is divergent.Thus,$L-E$ must be $0$. Thus, The tension at the resulting ends is the same.Repeat the same with different points on the string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to think about pulleys conceptually. One way is your way which is to imagine a cylindrical hub with radius $r$ that rotates. In this case, I like to think of the cylindrical hub as a gear with teeth that locks with the cable. If you take a cut into the cable and isolate the cable-hub system the free-body diagram looks like this:

[image: snip]

Note that there is still a portion of the cable in contact with the hub in this diagram. R is the reaction force from the ceiling holding up the hub, and L and E are tensions inside the cable from the load and effort, respectively. One assumption you can make is that the hub itself has a small radius and/or is virtually massless. In that case, its moment of inertia is zero. If its moment of inertia is zero, then the torques acting on it about its mounting point must balance, *even if it is experiencing an angular acceleration*. Then, your analysis is exactly correct, because L and E both act at a distance r from the mounting point, and their moments must balance. Also, the hub does not translate, so R balances L+E, even if the hub is massive.

Another way to conceptualize a pulley is as a fixed drum on which the cable may slide. In that case, the load will balance the effort if it is *frictionless.* Suppose it is not frictionless. Then a shear traction develops between the cable and drum. If L is bigger than E, then the free body diagram of the cable in contact with the drum looks like this in equilibrium:

[image]

The normal tractions do not contribute to a moment about O. But the shear tractions due to friction have a clockwise moment. E has a clockwise moment that is not as great as the counterclockwise moment from L. All torques are balanced. See the Capstan equation.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you think that  there is an infinite sum? If the tensions are not equal  the total  torque is $r(L-E)$.   If the pulley has moment of intertia $I$ we have $I\dot \omega = r(L-E)$, so it is only when $I=0$ that the tensions have to be the same.

For a mathematical  my formula for the torque note that
$$
\tau = \int_a^b \left(\frac{d T}{ds}\right) r ds = \left[ rT\right]_a^b=r(T(b)-T(a)
$$
where $a$ and $b$ are the first and last  points of contant of the string. This true because (for a massless sting)  Newton's thrd law tells us that  the tangential force on the pulley due to the contact of an infinitesimal   string element of length $dS$ is  the difference in the tension at the   two ends of the element.

Comment: I thought that the string applies a turning force at every point of its contact.

Comment: and then I considered the net moment . we see that moment about every point of contact is $Lr-Er$ and thus, summed the net moments about each point. Then,if I sum up the net moment about each point of contact, then I got the infinite which I thich gives the net moment that is $0$.

Comment: Is there something wrong?Please tell me.

Comment: Further,I have not got to integration part yet(I am a non-calculus blacksheep). I am staggered up in limits.

Comment: There are infinitely many points yes, but each contributes an infinitely-small torque and the result is  a finite answer,  That is what calculus is all about.